# Baking scalloped potatoes at 275 °F instead of at 400 °F

Tags: baking, temperature, potatoes

I have a single oven.  My ham needs to cook for 2 1/2 hours at 275 °F, my scalloped potatoes need to be cooked at 400 °F for 1 hour.

Do I put both dishes in the oven at 275 °F and if yes, when do I take my potatoes out?

Comment: Would you normally rest your ham? How long for? This may provide an opportunity for finishing the potatoes at a higher temperature. It's not so much about when you take them out, as when you put them in - you take them out just before serving, but they'll need extra time

Answer (score 2):

Timing can be more challenging than creating a meal itself. When this combo is part of a family gathering, I take timing out of the mix by baking the scalloped potatoes first, cover and set aside. Then do your ham. While the ham “rests”, to redistribute the juices, put the potatoes back in the oven, turn oven down to 300F & warm them. Good luck!

Comment: Agree here.  275 won't be enough to cook the potatoes, and worse, may cause very soggy potatoes even if they do cook throughout.  Cooking at a higher temperature is necessary for vegetables because some of the moisture will evaporate.

Answer (score 2):

Browning will not occur at 275 even if you leave the potatoes in the oven for days. So if you are happy with soft, creamy, pale potatoes, your method will work. But if you want a nice brown crust, you'll have to take out the ham and turn the oven up to 375 or more for the last 15 minutes or so of cooking.

Answer (score 0):

Scalloped potatoes will cook in 3 hours at 275°.  I have done it before and there are recipes that call for that time and temperature.